# Windows authentication without IIS when web api hosted as windows service

Tags: c#, .net

API returning result without authenticating and not asking for username and password similar to NTLM windows auth. How is .net authenticating?
I went through this ms documentation
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/windowsauth?view=aspnetcore-8.0&tabs=visual-studio#kestrel
I did configure as specified in the documentation for kestral

In Program.cs

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(NegotiateDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
   .AddNegotiate();

builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.FallbackPolicy = options.DefaultPolicy;
});
```

But it doesn't ask for windows username and password to authenticate the API endpoint

Controller

```
[Authorize]
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase
```

Also added this in the launch settings

```
"windowsAuthentication": true,
"anonymousAuthentication": false,
```